# Understanding conditional replacement

Tags: replacement

I have encountered recently a replacement and I tried to look up documentation but could not quite find anything and hope to get some explanation from experts.
The replacement is the following:

```
Gamma[2*x+c] /. Gamma[t:2*g_ + d_:0 ] -> 1/Sqrt[Pi]*2^(t-1)*Gamma[t/2]*Gamma[(t+1)/2]
```

I have never seen this way of conditional replacement. This gives correct replacement for any

```
Gamma[2*x+c].
```

What I want to know if anyone can explain the piece, what it does:

```
Gamma[t:2*g_ + d_:0 ]
```

What I understood is that whenever it sees argument of the type 2*x+c, it replaces and in the replaced output it does the following:

```
t-> 2*x+c
```

and +d_:0 is needed to recognise any argument of type

```
2*x+c
```

I will be grateful if anyone can explain this type of notations for replacement and what are the scopes and how it will look for multiple variable replacement.

Comment: `t:2*g_ + d_` matches  `2 x + c`,  `t:2*g_` matches `2 x`, and ``t:2*g_ + d_:0` (or ``t:2*g_ + d_.`) matches both `2x` and `2 x +c`.

Comment: The symbol t:2*g_ means that “t” is a name that on the right hand side represents 2*g_. In the second example d_:0 means that “0” is a default value that will be used in case “d” is not supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your expression and wrap it in `FullForm[HoldForm[expr]]` and it will spell out the details:

```
FullForm[HoldForm[
  Gamma[2*x + c] /. 
   Gamma[t : 2*g_ + d_: 0] -> 
    1/Sqrt[Pi]*2^(t - 1)*Gamma[t/2]*Gamma[(t + 1)/2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The construct

```
t:2*g_
```

is a shortcut for a named pattern. `t` represents the pattern object `2*g_` on the right hand side during the replacement.

The construct

```
d_:0
```

is a shortcut for `Optional`. It means that if that part of the pattern is omitted it will use `0` for `d` during the replacement.